# How to use switch case in onFileClick android

Tags: android, file, switch-statement, case

I'm trying to use a switch case to choose from a file ending with .txt, and one that ends .pdf, I've been practicing the switch case but just not as implemented in this case, My code is

```
private void onFileClick(Option o)
    {        
        Uri path = Uri.parse(o.getPath());
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } 
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(FileChooser.this, 
                "No Application Available to View PDF", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

I want to implement uri for .txt, .pdf, and others, in a case,  please helpme, and thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching on String values is a language feature of Java 7 and is not fully supported in Android (some have gotten it to work, but it takes some manipulation of the tools) which requires Java 5 or 6 if you are using ADT.

So selecting between String differences is best done with if-else, i.e.

```
Uri path = Uri.parse(o.getPath());
if ( path.getLastPathSegment().contains(".txt") ) {
    //TXT File
} else if ( path.getLastPathSegment().contains(".pdf") ) {
    //PDF File
} else {
    //Default case
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, It really worked, I did not know that switching on String values ​​is not fully supported in Android, and one more question, what I must replace for /pdf to open the .txt?
[code]intent.setDataAndType"application/pdf"...